# $.ajaxSetup({async:false}); stops mousemove event

Tags: jquery

This code stops mousemove event

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.get(url).success(function(data) { result = data; });
```

Is there a way to avoid this but keep $.ajaxSetup({async:false});, like a load function?

Thanks

Additions:

what if I need

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.get(url).success(function(data) { result = data; });
$.ajaxSetup({async:true});
return result
```

how to handle that?

Thanks

Comment: You do not want `$.ajaxSetup({async:false})`.

Comment: `async:false` halts the browser, all JavaScript, until it's done.

Comment: @Tomalak: I do need async:false, but I do not want halts...

Comment: @Oleksandr: No, you don't. I challenge you to name one single reason.

Comment: Well maybe I need another option, but what I need is to make url call, get results, and process results after that

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy: With AJAX, you want to do all the processing of the data in the callback.  Like this: `$.get(url, function(data){console.log(data);});`

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy:  You cannot return a value from an AJAX call.  It' doesn't work that way.  You need to do all the processing on the returned data in the callback.

Comment: @Tomalak: please review Addition section in my question. Thanks

Comment: @Rocket: i understand that, but how then to store returned result so I can use it later

Comment: @Oleksandr You are lacking basic knowledge about how asynchronous JavaScript works. Switching it off because you don't understand it will hurt you, because asynchronous calls are a good thing to have.

Comment: @Tomalak: I do understand how it works :). Just I need return result!!! I need get result from the server, but it should go step by step (in this case !!!)

Comment: @Oleksandr If you want to return a result from an asynchronous function, then you do not understand how it works. ;) Let go of that notion. You cannot and you do not need to return a value from such a function. That's what callback functions are for, use them instead of trying to return a value.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ok, Lets go another way, in php: $res = file_get_contents('http://blahblah.com'); echo $res;. What I need is that behavor, step by step. I like asynchronous, but I need step by step in THIS CASE ONLY!!!

Comment: @Oleksandr \*sighs\* You *never* need synchronous Ajax requests in a JavaScript application. There is not a single valid use for them. The problem you outline in your question is extremely common, it has been solved and the solution does not involve a synchronous request. Trust me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` implies synchronous code flow. AJAX is asynchronous without `async: false`, however. This does not mean you should use `async: false`. Rather, you should change your code flow to use callbacks instead of return values.

This is needed since there is no way to make the asynchronous code synchronous (i.e. you can't use `return` with asynchronous functions). The only way is to provide a callback yourself as well:

```
function get(url, callback) {
    $.get(url).success(function(data) { callback(data); });
}
```

Like:

```
get("...", function(result) {
    // use `result` which you normally got by assigning the return value
    // of `get` to a variable
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should find a way to do what you want without setting `async:false`.

Using the callbacks from your ajax request you should be able to do most things.

Comment: have added addition to my question, please check

Answer (score 3):

`async:false` halts the browser, and all JavaScript, until the AJAX call is done.  There's no way around this.

What you should do is, instead of trying to return a value from an AJAX call, you should do all processing of the data inside your callback.

You can save the returned data to a global variable, but it won't be available until it's done.